# R connecting to Local SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I cannot connect to my local sql server through Rstudio. I am able to connect to a SQL Server that my company hosts and I can connect to my local SQL Server  through Management Studio. What am I doing wrong?

Is there something I need to do to connect locally? The `(LocalDB)\v11.0` was the exact server name that I connect to my local SQL Server through Management Studio.

```
install.packages("RODBC")

library(RODBC)

dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server;Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=NBA;trusted_connection=yes")
```

The error message I get is the following:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server;Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=NBA;trusted_connection=yes") :
>   [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
>
> 2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server;Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=NBA;trusted_connection=yes") :
>   [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 53, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
>
> 3: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server;Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=NBA;trusted_connection=yes") :  ODBC connection failed

Comment: Also, you can see a line break, `\n` in the connection string since you break it in R which may be calling an unrecognized server instance. Try running connection string on one line.

Comment: updated error message without the line break

Comment: See connection string examples [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). You seem to be connecting to a local instance and not explicit server. Try `Integrated Security=true;` instead of `trusted_connection=yes`.

Comment: I made the change and still received the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try **double backslash**...
I tried the following and it's working fine:

```
library(odbc)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server;Server=(local)\\SQLSERVER2016;Database=Test_DB;trusted_connection=yes")
data <- sqlFetch(dbconnection, 'dbo.temp_table', colnames=FALSE, rows_at_time=1000)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I downloaded a newer version of SQL Server and then used the suggestion above and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but it was caused by a different problem. For some reason `{SQL Server}` did not allow me to connect to Local SQL Server but changing it to `{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}` worked.

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server= (local)\\SQLSERVER2016;Database=Test_DB;trusted_connection=yes")
```

Turns out that SQL Server driver known as `SQL Server ODBC Driver` is an old driver whereas `SQL Server Native Client` contains both the `SQL OLE DB` provider and `SQL ODBC driver` to support native connectivity to SQL Server.